# Using selenium, can I get the text of an invisible element?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium, can I get the text of an invisible element?   I tried to do it using  driver.getElement().getText()  but I am getting an empty string.

```
<p id="versionInfo" style="display: none;">
    4.7.2<br/>
    20130714-1512
</p>
</footer></body>
```

Comment: You could use java script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try javascript executor.I haven't tried it before though i was able perform click operations over invisible elements.

```
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 String text= executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('versionInfo').innerHTML");
```

Comment: Yes, this is the only option

Answer (score 37):

Javascript is not necessary, obtain the value through the textContext attribute.

```
var text = driver.FindElement(By.Id("demo-div")).GetAttribute("textContent")
```

http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/#c-sharp

Comment: This is what I am looking for instead of `getAttribute("value")`. It works well without `JavascriptExecutor`. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in Python as well using `.get_attribute('textContent')`

Comment: @he_the_great your solution works nicely for input elements, however, when it is a hidden select element with multiple options, all options are retrieved instead of the selected one. How can you get only the selected one on a hidden select element?

Comment: @poyson1, I don't know, but I thought I observed that using the normal selected item methods ignored that the control was not displayed. I.e you don't do anything special to get selected values of hidden elements.

Comment: you're a saviour